# Music Genre API?

Tags: php, api

Does anyone know of any Music APIs that let you query with a song name, and return a genre?

i.e. `http://foo.bar/api/?song=Baby&artist=Justin+Bieber` and have the return be 'Pop'?

I'm making an app that relies on the sole interesting feature being Prediction, yet I need the Genre to determine some extra data!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the last.fm API: http://www.last.fm/api/show?service=356

Here is an example of the XML returned: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getinfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&artist=cher&track=believe

You have to give it at least the artist and track name & you get tags back, these are very similar to genre but not the same, they are also created by users.

**artist**=cher&**track**=believe gives:

```
<toptags>
<tag>
<name>pop</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/pop</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>dance</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/dance</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>90s</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/90s</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>cher</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/cher</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>female vocalists</name>
<url>http://www.last.fm/tag/female%20vocalists</url>
</tag>
</toptags>
```

It has some great features like realising when you spelled an artist's name wrong.

Comment: +1 for suggesting something relevant. Thank you for your answer! And your code example! :) But, I don't live in the US/UK, and cannot use the Last.fm API :( Which kinda sucks :(

Comment: Then again, I could just *steal* XML from the code examples, haha

Comment: You need to use your own API key, I didn't realise the API was limited to certain countries.

Answer (score 4):

You could look at EchoNest, but I don't know whether it will be useful to you: http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/song.html

Comment: This is the one I just stumbled across, looking in to it now, but it only gives the genres for artists as opposed to individual songs, which is alright, but I really need one for each individual song, i.e. 'Eminem' does both rap and pop, which makes it a bit difficult :(

Answer (score 3):

you can try the last.fm api by query for a song and get afterwards the artist-info for the query-result. the artist-info contains not exactly the genre, but a list of tags that will be used as a categorization for a track

Comment: +1 for suggesting something relevant. Thank you for your answer! But, I don't live in the US/UK, and cannot use the Last.fm API :(

Answer (score 0):

Gracenote has a developer program that delivers genre info for artists and tracks https://developer.gracenote.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.TheAudioDB.com can do this [via their api](http://www.theaudiodb.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7)

```
 http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/{APIKEY}/searchtrack.php?s={Artist_Name}&t={Single_Name}
```

Should give you lots of info including a single genre.